# Multiple constraints in generic class

Tags: generics, flutter, dart

How can I perform **Multiple Constraints** in Generic class in dart lang

```
class ClassA<T implements ClassB<T> & ClassC<T>>  {
}
```

Like C# Code

```
class EmployeeList<T> where T : Employee, IEmployee, System.IComparable<T>, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible.

The best thing you can have is to make an abstract class that implement both interfaces at once, and use that as constraints instead.